# Slow down when hashing a file

Tags: c#, wcf, hash, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to get the hash of a file stored in the Windows Azure Blob Store.

I'm hoping to then compare the hash with the version stored on the local machine to see if there is a difference.

The following code get the hash.

```
        _CloudBlobClient = SetupCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer cbContainer = _CloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(sContainer);
        CloudBlockBlob cbBlob = cbContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sBlob);

        BlobStream stream = cbBlob.OpenRead();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        MD5 md5 = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
        foreach (byte b in hash)
            sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));

        return sb.ToString();
```

The problem is that this works fine for small files but I'm working with files larger than 100MB and for those files the service just takes too long and eventually times out.

I'm wondering if this is the right approach to take or if there is another way to determine if two files contain the same data which would work faster for large files.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken the problem is that you are downloading the whole file here:

```
byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
```

That explains why this will get very slow on big files and probably is not feasible as a solution - I don't have any perfect alternative but an idea would be to only generate the MD5 hash i.e. on the first 5 KB of data and additionally compare the file size - if both match, assume they are identical.

Comment: I had a feeling it was probably something to do with that, since I upload the files in 2MB chunks I'm now creating the hash from the first 2MB. 
            int length = ((int)stream.Length > 2048000) ? 2048000 : (int)stream.Length;
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[length];
            stream.Read(Buffer, 0, length);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(Buffer);

It's not ideal but it will have to do for now, Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may take another approach. Each time a new file is stored and/or overwritten, keep a version number anywhere (database, another related file,...). When getting the files locally, get also this version, so it's easy to compare.
Of course I have no idea about your system, so maybe this is not possible at all...